# for one to one relationship, which option should i select?

Tags: entity-framework

I guess withmany and withoptional both will be wrong

```
    modelBuilder.Entity<Student>().HasRequired(c => 
c.Studentaccount).WithMany(s => s.student).HasForeignKey(s => s.StudentId);
```

Answer (score 0):

HasOptional

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Student>().HasRequired(c => c.Studentaccount).HasOptional(s => s.student);
```

For all the relationship in EF you can have a look to the official MSDN page
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj591620.aspx